# Grails. spring security core. Install problem

Tags: plugins, grails, spring-security

I try install Spring security core plugin in Grails.
I run this command:

```
grails install-plugin spring-security-core
```

and in result i see this error message:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

      C:\STS\LoginProject/lib/spring-security-core-[revision].zip

      C:\Documents and Settings\fenuk\.grails\1.3.5\projects\LoginProject\plugins\hibernate-1.3.5/lib/spring-security-core-[revision].zip

      C:\Documents and Settings\fenuk\.grails\1.3.5\projects\LoginProject\plugins\tomcat-1.3.5/lib/spring-security-core-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-1.3.5\lib/spring-security-core-[revision].xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

      C:\grails-1.3.5\lib/spring-security-core-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\grails-1.3.5\dist/spring-security-core-[revision].xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

      C:\grails-1.3.5\dist/spring-security-core-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

      C:\grails-1.3.5/plugins/grails-spring-security-core-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-spring-security-core-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration!spring-security-core.zip:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-spring-security-core-[revision].zip

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;latest.integration: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error resolving plugin [name:spring-security-core, group:org.grails.plugins, version:latest.integration].
Plugin not found for name [spring-security-core] and version [not specified]
```

what this error mean? maybe, i do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have at least the three core repositories in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
   grailsPlugins()
   grailsHome()
   grailsCentral()
}
```

As a temporary workaround, you can install it directly by downloading the zip file. Go to http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core and click the big Download button, then install from the zip by running

```
grails install-plugin path/to/grails-spring-security-core-1.0.1.zip
```

You can also install it without downloading using

```
grails install-plugin http://plugins.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_0_1/grails-spring-security-core-1.0.1.zip
```

But I suspect you have a network issue, so the plugin install will fail since it uses Ivy to resolve the required Spring Security jars, and that download may also fail.

Comment: I was able to install using the URL.  This had worked prior to installing the STS grails plugin.  After installing the STS plugin, stuff seemed to break. :(