# Grails spring-security-core plugin installation never completes

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using Grails 1.3.7
Windows 7

I've tried this on a brand new grails project...althouGh i have other grails versions installed on the system (no longer in PATH however).

When executing grails install-plugin spring-security-core the installation never completes leaving me with the following which never completes:

---

Environment set to development
Resolving plugin spring-security-core. Please wait...
....

....
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/spring
framework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.4.RELEASE/org.springfra
mework.security.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.pom ...
Download complete.
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/org/spring
framework/security/org.springframework.security.core/3.0.4.RELEASE/org.springfra
mework.security.core-3.0.4.RELEASE.pom.sha1 ...
Download complete.

---

Any options other than installing manually?

I've deleted the .grails and .ivy directories to try to clean up but still no luck.

adding BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${grails.util.Environment.current.name}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // uncomment to disable ehcache
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    repositories {
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        // uncomment the below to enable remote dependency resolution
        // from public Maven repositories
        //mavenLocal()
        //mavenCentral()
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the content of your BuildConfig.groovy

Answer (score 0):

the spring security v1.1 plugins causes some issues. 
[Grails. spring security core. Install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344267/grails-spring-security-core-install-problem)

I installed the v1.0.1 version

```
grails install-plugin spring-security-core 1.0.1
```

worked for me