# Error while installing spring-security-plugin in Grails app

Tags: grails

I am trying to install the spring-security-core plugin in my grails application. I am working on a 32 bit windows application. However I am unable to install the same. I have tried all workarounds specified in the below link, but to no avail.

[Grails. spring security core. Install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344267/grails-spring-security-core-install-problem)

I keep getting the 'Unresolved Jar dependencies' error while trying the work arounds.

Thoughts??

EDIT:

```
C:\MyProjects\Twitter>grails install-plugin spring-security-core-1.2.1
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: C:\MyProjects\Twitter
Resolving dependencies...
  Dependencies resolved in 1765ms.
Running script C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7\scripts\InstallPlugin.groovy
Environment set to development
Resolving plugin spring-security-core-1.2.1. Please wait...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            module not found: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;
latest.integration

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      C:\MyProjects\Twitter/lib/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].zip

      D:\Documents and Settings\alex\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Twit
ter\plugins\hibernate-1.3.7/lib/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].zip

      D:\Documents and Settings\alex\.grails\1.3.7\projects\Twit
ter\plugins\tomcat-1.3.7/lib/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7\lib/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].xm
l

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7\lib/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].zi
p

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7\dist/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].x
ml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7\dist/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].z
ip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      C:\Softwares\grails-1.3.7/plugins/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.1-[r
evision].zip

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core-1.2
.1/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].zip

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-spring-secu
rity-core-1.2.1/tags/LATEST_RELEASE/grails-spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision]
.zip

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core-
1.2.1/[revision]/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integ
ration!spring-security-core-1.2.1.zip:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core-
1.2.1/[revision]/spring-security-core-1.2.1-[revision].zip

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core-1.2.1;latest.integrat
ion: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.mave
n.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core-1.2.1/maven-metadata.xml

Error resolving plugin [name:spring-security-core-1.2.1, group:org.grails.plugin
s, version:latest.integration].
Plugin not found for name [spring-security-core-1.2.1] and version [not specifie
d]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the output from Grails?

Comment: what have you entered `grails install-plugin ??`? If you do not remember, check your application.properties, whether there is an item for spring-security-core. have you entered a version number? try `grails install-plugin spring-security-core-2.1` or let your IDE do it for you (STS).

Comment: Thanks Crudolf...I guess I missed that...However even after installing with the version name, I am getting similar errors. Also it shows a connection error, I am assuming its a netwrk issue. Have updated the question with the error too. Is there a work around???

Comment: sorry i confused you with wrong version number: `grails install-plugin spring-security-core-1.1.3`. hope its working now. you can use eclipse STS, which will give you a GUI for all plugins. then it should not happen again. good luck ;)

Comment: Sorry Crudolf..It still is giving me the same error trace...is there any work around for this...there might be network issue that I am facing, coz i keep getting Connection Timed out error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with my internet connection. Got through the installation when I did it using my home computer.