# Spring Security Core Plugin with grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using grails 2.3.3 via a GGTS 3.4.0 in a development application and I now want to start to use the Spring security core plugin.

I have tried to include it, unsuccessfully, in my application build by adding into plugin part of the BuildConfig.groovy file the line:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
```

But get this dependency error on that plugin when doing a run-app:

> Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies

looking at another note I tried:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"
```

in the plugin part of the buildconfig file and:

```
        mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
```

in the repositories part of the the file with the same dependency error issue.

Have I got the wrong version of the plugin for the version of grails/GGTS that I'm using?

Here is the current BuildConfig.groovy :

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container     compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.work.dir = 'target'
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to    disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info',  'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()

    mavenCentral()

    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency  resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"

    mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'

    grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"

}
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime',  'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"


}

plugins {
    //runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"

    //compile 'utils:utils:1.4-SNAPSHOT'

    compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.4"

    //runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
    runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"

    //runtime ':pvpi:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    //runtime (':pvpi:0.1'){
        //changing = true
    //}

    //runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.1"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:7.0.47"
    //build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    //runtime ":database-migration:1.1"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"

    //compile ':cache:1.0.0'
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'

    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.0"

    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"

    }
}
```

The logs sent to the console display all the online locations that the build goes to try and find the the spring-security-core software - here is a list of all these locations:

> grailsCentral: http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.pom
>
> mavenCentral: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.pom
>
> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.pom
>
> http://repo.spring.io/milestone/: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.pom
>
> http://grails.org/plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_3.1.1/spring-security-core-3.1.1.pom

-mike

Answer (score 1):

What if you try with

```
compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"
```

in your BuildConfig.groovy plugins section

Comment: In the plugin section I have tried a variety of versions of the spring-security-core plugin without any success. Perhaps I need to add a another line into the 'repositories' section of buildconfig file? Alternatively, could I download the plugin explicitly - if so not sure what to do exactly? I can see the file grails-spring-security-core-master.zip can be downloaded from the github site but I'm not sure how to use this? Also, would this newer version of the security core work with Grails 2.3.3?

Comment: Have you followed the steps for configuration that are mentioned  in documentation : https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#s2-quickstart ?

Comment: I've just included the full Buildconfig.groovy file in the initial question above. The main changes I've made to try and link in spring-security are to add the `mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'` and the `grailsRepo "http://grails.org/plugins"` lines in the repositories block, the `compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"` into the dependencies block and the `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"` into the plugins block.

Comment: I've just seen this earlier stackoverflow question: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344267/grails-spring-security-core-install-problem?rq=1  which clearly explains how to install the plugin directly from a zip file. I can download the most recent version from the security-core documentation page the current version being is: 3.0.4-1. Will this work with grails 2.3.3? If not where can I source an earlier version?

Comment: Am still unable to link this plugin into my application - I'm using the dependency as stated at the top of the grail spring security core plugin web page: org.grails.plugins#spring-security-core;2.0.0 but I get the error message 'Module not found'  when building the app I've also tried version 3.1.0 as suggested in the reference documentation again with the same error.

Comment: Hi! I try with a new project and I guest that you forget select the dependency resolver, in my case I have this line `grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy` before of the line `grails.project.dependency.resolution = {` and offcourse don't forget the compile line `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC5"` I have only that in my BuildConfig.groovy file and the security plugin was installed ok.

Comment: Yes - by adding the resolver= "maven" the app now builds - that's great. Using 'ivy' didn't work. I'm now not getting any unresolved issues but I am getting a message that grailsRepo has been deprecated. I guess that this is simply redundant now.

Comment: very good!!! I haven't read about ivy, but may be it need to have other configurations.

Comment: @JuanParra - Your link above is dead - certificate management is now non-optional in chrome and you get end of file errors in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the follow link above to take the last version of this pluggin.

https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/

Right now, the correct command is:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1"
```

Works for me.

Comment: This question was about grails 2 - not about grails 3.